# How do I make a page visible with or without ending slash in the url?

Tags: clojure, ring, noir

I use noir.

Having :

```
(defpage "/welcome" [] "Welcome to Noir!")
```

I do I make both these URL works:

```
http://localhost:8080/welcome 
http://localhost:8080/welcome/
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's the complete answer.

In `server.clj`, add up `(:use [ring.util.response :only [redirect]])`

Then write :

```
(defn wrap-slash 
  ""
  [handler]
  (fn [{:keys [uri] :as req}]
    (if (and (.endsWith uri "/") (not= uri "/"))
      (handler (assoc req :uri (.substring uri
                                0 (dec (count uri)))))
      (handler req))))

(server/add-middleware wrap-slash)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noir's routing is more strict than some others, so take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469914/how-to-do-http-302-redirects-with-noir-web-framework) which, while having a different title, is asking the same thing.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. The other question talk about redirection. When I type .../welcome/ , I don't want the URL to change to .../welcome in the browser. I just want both URLS possible and point to the same content. Does the answer to the other question supports this?

Comment: It appears it works perfectly! Thanks very much. I put an edit on my question that take the answer of the other question and add a context of how to use it: `(server/add-middleware wrap-slash)`. This was lacking in the other answer, or at least, it wasn't explicit...